# Using PHPExcel to store utf-8 characters to a file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to write a string having utf characters into excel using PHPExcel. But it is not getting written as expected. Below is the sample code.

I tried different solutions provided at stackoverflow but none of them work may be I could not be able to understand properly as this is the first time I am working in PHP.

I am giving below sample code for my problem. This sample string has been taken from mysql table in actual implementation and I have applied "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin" to support utf-8.

If I do like below and print to browser then it works fine with "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" header.

What is wrong in below code? How to fix this? Special character is big hyphen

```
<?php
$libdir='/home/user';
include_once($libdir.'/PHPExcel.php');
include_once($libdir.'/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');
$workBook = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $workBook->getActiveSheet();
$str = 'i m &#8211 here';
$str = utf8_decode($str);
//echo STDERR $str;  if it print here then i will get proper string "&#8211 will be converted to big hyphen)
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 0, $str);
$filename = "abc.xls";
header('Content-type: application/xls');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
$writer   = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($workBook);
$cache_dir = "/home/user/cache";
$writer->save($cache_dir/$filename);
readfile($cache_dir/$filename);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'&#8211'
```

is a HTML Number.

Use it like this to get the original value:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#8211;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Hope this helps.